# Deployment of a Pyramid App to Openshift with openshift-quickstarter

Tags: python, openshift, pyramid

I'm having some troubles deploying my Pyramid app to Openshift. This is my [aplication](https://github.com/Rogergonzalez21/g8corp_test)

In the "Openshift Pyramid deployment" page they recommend using "openshift-quickstarter", but I don't know where to clone it! My app is ready and running, and I just have this issue.

I've cloned it in /g8test and it ran OK, but when I go to the URL it says "server error". If you can help me with this, I'll be very thankfull.

[This is the application](http://g8test-rogergonzalez.rhcloud.com/) I created in with "openshift-quickstarter":

Comment: I have a openshift pyramid starter on github . Search github or stackoverflow. It was a question here also.

Comment: Check it out. https://github.com/fatfantasma/Openshift-Pyramidstarter

Comment: How do I use it? Do I have to create only "wsgi.py"? or do i have to clone the repo?  @fatfantasma

Comment: There is a stackoverflow post that describes everything. Search for it under my name. I'm still waking up :).  However, I would use 'app.py' method and not wsgi.py. It's a better way to go.

Comment: You will have to create the app.py file.  Openshift looks for app.py or wsgi.py.

Comment: Ok ok, i'll clone them from your repo and upload it @fatfantasma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use my openshift pyramid starter

https://github.com/fatfantasma/Openshift-Pyramidstarter